# Android Phone app crashes as soon as I run it on a phone

Tags: android, eclipse, crash

I'm trying to just create a basic android app, and when I load it onto a phone and try to run the app it just crashes. Can someone take a look at it for me?

My manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.workexp1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What logcat says

```
07-02 15:19:24.091: D/AndroidRuntime(3213): Shutting down VM
07-02 15:19:24.091: W/dalvikvm(3213): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workexp1/com.example.workexp1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.workexp1.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.workexp1-1.apk]
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1785)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1893)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.workexp1.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.workexp1-1.apk]
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1777)
07-02 15:19:24.101: E/AndroidRuntime(3213):     ... 11 more
07-02 15:19:31.869: D/Process(3213): killProcess, pid=3213
```

Request any other files you'd need to check.

Comment: please include where exactly in your project packages the MainActivity.java file is located.

Comment: You probably don't have an activity called MainActivity, or there is something stopping it from compiling (compilation error)

Comment: Post the mainactivity file.

Comment: post your activity file i'll help you

Comment: Show code of MainActivity.java

Comment: I can't find the MainActivity, also, my source code file is empty. Any ideas on fixing this. Thanks also for the responses, first question and all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.workexp1.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.workexp1-1.apk]`

This exception means that there is no such class named `MainActivity` in your project. So check your project and see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem and now it runs

Answer (score 0):

If you MainActivity does not live in the same package as the one specified in the manifest (in this case com.example.workexp1) then the dot notation won't work.

change this line

```
android:name=".MainActivity">
```

to

```
android:name="com.yourfullpackage.MainActivity">
```